# Combining 2 arrays into their own arrays React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays that I used the map() function to add to an array, but the problem I'm having is they are being grouped by name and grouped by review but I want them to return name + review independently of each other when I click submit on my form. Here's an example of what's happening:

[image]

I want it so David's review ("great movie") is separate from Daniel's review ("my favorite").

I've tried all sorts of things to no avail. Here is my code:

````
import { Button, Form, Input } from "reactstrap";
import Stars from "./stars";

export default function ReviewForm() {
  const [reviewinput, setReviewInput] = useState("");
  const [reviewarray, setReviewArray] = useState([]);
  const [nameinput, setNameInput] = useState("");
  const [namearray, setNameArray] = useState([])
  const [starinput, setStarInput] = useState();
  const [stararr, setStarArr] = useState(0)

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setReviewInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const onChangeName = (e) => {
    setNameInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
    if (reviewinput) {
      reviewarray.push(reviewinput);
      setReviewArray(reviewarray);
    }
    if (nameinput) {
      namearray.push(nameinput);
      setNameArray(namearray);
    }
    if (starinput) {
      stararr.push(starinput);
      setStarArr(stararr);
    }
      setReviewInput('');
      setNameInput('');
      setStarInput(0)
  };
  console.log(reviewarray);
  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Stars setStar={setStarArr} />
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Input
            className="form-control" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            value={nameinput}
            onChange={onChangeName}
          />
        <Input
          className="form-control"
          type="textarea"
          placeholder="Enter your review"
          value={reviewinput}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div className="card-header border boorder-dark">
          <h5>Reviews</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body border border-secondary">
          {namearray.map((name, i) => <p key={i}>{name}</p>)}
          <br></br>
          {reviewarray.map((review, i) => <p key={i}>{review}</p>)}
          <p>I rate it this movie {stararr} stars!</p>
          </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

// STAR COMPONENT \\

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar} from 'react-icons/fa'

const Stars = ({ setStar }) => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
  
    const handleClick = (ratingValue) => {
      setRating(ratingValue);
      setStar(ratingValue);
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
          const ratingValue = i + 1;
          return (
            <label key={i}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="rating"
                value={ratingValue}
                onClick={() => handleClick(ratingValue)}
              />
              <FaStar
                className="star"
                color={ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? "gold" : "lightgray"}
                size={20}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratingValue)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
              />
            </label>
          );
        })}
        <p>I rate this movie {rating + " stars"}</p>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Stars;```
````

Comment: so you want the namearray above the reviews? why cant you just simply move it to another div? I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: When you submit, I want the person's name and review in their own div, together, I suppose is what I'm saying. Right now when I click submit its grouping the names together and the reviews together as show in my screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to do this using an object instead of combining two arrays.

Make each review an object that contains a review, name, and your stars like so:

```
{
    name: 'a',
    review: 'good',
    stars: 5
}
```

This way you could just use one array and push that object instead.

The reason your stars wasn't updating to 0 is because in your ./stars file you made a new stars state when you could have just re-used the one from your main component. Other than that, your code was fine.

updated code:

main file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Input } from "reactstrap";
import Stars from "./stars";

export default function ReviewForm() {
  const [reviewinput, setReviewInput] = useState("");
  const [reviewarray, setReviewArray] = useState([]);
  const [nameinput, setNameInput] = useState("");
  const [stararr, setStarArr] = useState(0);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setReviewInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const onChangeName = (e) => {
    setNameInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");

    const review = {};

    if (reviewinput) {
      review.review = reviewinput;
    }
    if (nameinput) {
      review.name = nameinput;
    }
    review.stars = stararr;
    setReviewArray([...reviewarray, review]);
    setReviewInput("");
    setNameInput("");
    setStarArr(0);
    const form = e.target
    form.reset() /* to reset radio buttons to initial */
  };
  console.log(reviewarray);
  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Stars setStar={setStarArr} stararr={stararr} />
        <Input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name"
          value={nameinput}
          onChange={onChangeName}
          required
        />
        <Input
          className="form-control"
          type="textarea"
          placeholder="Enter your review"
          value={reviewinput}
          onChange={onChange}
          required
        />
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div className="card-header border boorder-dark">
          <h5>Reviews</h5>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body border border-secondary">
          <br></br>
          {reviewarray.map(({ review, name, stars }, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <p>name: {name}</p>
              <p>review: {review}</p>
              <p>stars: {stars}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
          <p>I rate it this movie {stararr} stars!</p>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

star component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";

const Stars = ({ setStar, stararr }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (ratingValue) => {
    setStar(ratingValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
        const stararr = i + 1;
        return (
          <label key={i}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              value={stararr}
              onClick={() => handleClick(stararr)}
            />
            <FaStar
              className="star"
              color={stararr <= (hover || stararr) ? "gold" : "lightgray"}
              size={20}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(stararr)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
            />
          </label>
        );
      })}
      <p>I rate this movie {stararr + " stars"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stars;
```

Edit: To incorporate the stars input as well

For your stars component I just replaced  wherever you had `ratings` to your original stars value.

Comment: Duh, objects! This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. One last question - how would I get the star rating to also transfer over? It's wonky at the moment - it submits the value but doesn't clear and also seems to be controlled by star component up top as well, meaning if you change it after submitting it also changes in the review at the bottom.

Comment: You didn't share the ./stars file, so I cant quite say for sure. But you should be able to just add it to your object so it would have 3 properties { review, name, stars}, then the rest should be the same as the other properties. If its not clearing with `setStarInput(0);`, then seems to be an issue with your star.js code

Comment: I added the Star component. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Please edit it in your question.

Comment: Removed from your comment and added to my question!

Comment: Thanks Bas, that did the trick. I wish I could buy you a drink! :)

Comment: Just curious - do you know why the star rating doesn't reset to 0 after form submission? The text goes back to zero, but 5 stars stay highlighted.

Comment: `const form = e.target; form.reset()` /* to reset radio buttons to initial */. If that's what you meant

Comment: I meant like even before they're clicked on they show 5 stars and after form submission as well. They rating is correct (the text reads out how many stars you rated) but never shows anything but 5 highlighted stars at all times. To simplify, I guess what I'm looking for is the default color to be gray and ony change to gold on mouse-over and when they are clicked!

Comment: Maybe set the hover state in your parent component then pass that? This way you could in your onSubmit function reset the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to achieve this. What you want to do is to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (at least Python developers would use this term), so that means you want to group together the first, second, third, ... element of the two given arrays. Then you could [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the resulting array and display the values as you please.

For your example you could just use something like the following using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const names = ["Thomas", "Peter", "Tom", "Mark", "John"];
const reviews = [
  "Well, this was shit.",
  "Love me some sharks",
  "Sharknadoooo!",
  "It's a terrible joy.",
  "I've seen a peanut stand, I've heard a rubber band, I've seen a needle wink it's eye, but I ain't never seen a Shark fly",
];

const result = names.map((name, idx) => ({ name: name, review: reviews[idx] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In a more general sense with any number of arrays you could use a [generator function](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-generators.html) although you could do it without one. But this is a quite convenient and simple way to achieve what you want which generates the values as you need them when using `for ... of`.

```js
const names = ["Thomas", "Peter", "Tom", "Mark", "John"]
const reviews = ["Well, this was shit.", "Love me some sharks", "Sharknadoooo!", "It's a terrible joy.", "I've seen a peanut stand, I've heard a rubber band, I've seen a needle wink it's eye, but I ain't never seen a Shark fly"]

/**
 * Zips any number of arrays. It will always zip() the largest array returning undefined for shorter arrays.
 * @param  {...Array<any>} arrays 
 */
function* zip(...arrays){
  const maxLength = arrays.reduce((max, curIterable) => curIterable.length > max ? curIterable.length: max, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    yield arrays.map(array => array[i]);
  }
}

// put them in a array
const test = [...zip(names, reviews)]
console.log(test);

// or lazy generate the values
for (const [name, review] of zip(names, reviews)) {
  console.log(`${name}: ${review}`);  
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Bas bas told you, I think it's better to combine the name and the review in the same item in the reviews array.

I also wrote it a bit shorter and understandable:

```
import { Button, Form, Input } from "reactstrap";
import Stars from "./stars";

export default function ReviewForm() {
  const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState("");
  const [reviewInput, setReviewInput] = useState("");
  const [starInput, setStarInput] = useState(0);
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (!nameInput || !nameInput.length || !reviewInput || !reviewInput.length || isNaN(starInput)) {
        return;
    }
    
    setReviews((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        name: nameInput,
        review: reviewInput,
        rating: starInput
      }
    ]);

    clearForm();
  };
  
  const clearForm = () => {
    setNameInput('');
    setReviewInput('');
    setStarInput(0);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Stars setStar={setStarInput} />
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Input
          className="form-control" type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name"
          value={nameInput}
          onChange={(e) => setNameInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          className="form-control"
          type="textarea"
          placeholder="Enter your review"
          value={reviewInput}
          onChange={(e) => setReviewInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div className="card-header border boorder-dark">
          <h5>Reviews</h5>
                </div>
        <div className="card-body border border-secondary">
          {reviews.map(({ name, review }, i) => 
            <p key={i}>{name} - {review}</p>
          )}
         </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```